# Connection refused in Tornado test

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to create tests for a Tornado code base I'm picking up. I get the project to run fine but the first test I've written is getting a connection refused error.

Here's the code:

```
import unittest, os, os.path, sys, urllib
import tornado.options
from tornado.options import options
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase


APP_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(APP_ROOT, '..'))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)))

from main import Application

app = Application()

def clear_db(app=None):
    os.system("mysql -u user --password=pw --database=testdb < %s" % (os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'db', 'schema.sql')))

class TestHandlerBase(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        clear_db()
        super(TestHandlerBase, self).setUp()

    def get_app(self):
        return app

    def get_http_port(self):
        return 5000

class TestRootHandler(TestHandlerBase):
    def test_redirect(self):
        response = self.fetch(
            '/',
            method='GET',
            follow_redirects=False)
        print response
        self.assertTrue(response.headers['Location'].endswith('/login'))
```

This is the response I get:

```
HTTPResponse(_body=None, buffer=None, code=599, 
  effective_url='http://localhost:5000/',
  error=HTTPError('HTTP 599: [Errno 61] Connection refused',), 
  headers={}, reason='Unknown', 
  request=<tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest object at 0x10c363510>, 
  request_time=0.01304006576538086, time_info={})
```

Any idea on what might be causing the error? Is there a step I'm missing to get everything running for the test? Thanks!!!

Comment: ECONNREFUSED is a pretty basic IP level diagnostic which says "I tried to talk to localhost:5000 and it affirmatively told me to go away". This usually means that there is a) no server bound to port 5000 or b) there is some local firewall or other permissions problem.

Comment: The command `telnet localhost 5000` will quickly help you rule out a problem with your application. If you get connection refused with that, it ain't your app.

Answer (score 4):

Don't override `get_http_port`. A new HTTP server with a new port is setup for each test, so it won't be 5000 every time, even if that's what you have in your settings.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer by Cole Maclean

If you need to configure custom URL, then override the below method of AsyncHTTPTestCase

```
def get_url(self, path):
    url = 'http://localhost:8080' + path
    return url
```

In this scenario, this will take the URL as ***http://localhost:8080*** by default.